# Is there a reason I cannot get the current category in a loop?

Tags: categories, loop, tags, conditional-tags

I think I am doing this wrong but if I do:

```
if(have_posts()){
    $category_id = get_query_var('cat');
var_dump($category_id);
    while (have_posts()){
        the_post();
    }
}
```

the var dump comes back empty. Why? Is there a better way to get the current category object in a loop? the same question applies to tags. Can I also get the current tag object if this was a `is_tag()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_query_var` will get the category from the main query, and it is only going to be set for some pages, such as category archives. It is not set for "single" pages or tag archives or a many other kids of "pages".

The value that `get_query_var` returns is something like a 'search' variable. It will be set when the query is instructed to look for posts in a particular category. It doesn't reflect the value of current post in the Loop, though of course if `get_query_var('cat')` is set then all posts should be assigned to that category.

What you want to get the category for the current post in the Loop is [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category), but it should come after `the_post`. [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) will do the same for tags and the more generic [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) can be used for any taxonomy.